# Extract text between link tags in python using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, text, tags, extract, beautifulsoup

I  have an html code like this:

`<h2 class="title"><a href="http://www.gurletins.com">My HomePage</a></h2>`

`<h2 class="title"><a href="http://www.gurletins.com/sections">Sections</a></h2>`

I need to extract the texts (link descriptions) between 'a' tags. I need an array to store these like:

a[0] = "My HomePage"

a[1] = "Sections"

I need to do this in python using BeautifulSoup.

Please help me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<html><head></head>
<body>
<h2 class='title'><a href='http://www.gurletins.com'>My HomePage</a></h2>
<h2 class='title'><a href='http://www.gurletins.com/sections'>Sections</a></h2>
</body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)

print [elm.a.text for elm in soup.findAll('h2', {'class': 'title'})]
# Output: [u'My HomePage', u'Sections']
```

Comment: @Mehmet Helvaci: can you be more specific of what didn't work ? did you get some error or .. , the code above as i posted work correctly for me.

Answer (score 0):

print [a.findAll(text=True) for a in soup.findAll('a')]

Answer (score 0):

The following code extracts text (link descriptions) between 'a' tags and stores in an array.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> data = """<h2 class="title"><a href="http://www.gurletins.com">My 
HomePage</a></h2>
...
... <h2 class="title"><a href="http://www.gurletins.com/sections">Sections</a>
</h2>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
>>> reqTxt = soup.find_all("h2", {"class":"title"})
>>> a = []
>>> for i in reqTxt:
...     a.append(i.get_text())
...
>>> a
['My HomePage', 'Sections']
>>> a[0]
'My HomePage'
>>> a[1]
'Sections'
```