# Python beautifulsoup extract date between <a> tag (and associate it with his own url)

Tags: python, string, tags, beautifulsoup

I have this HTML line to parse: (original line)

```
<h4 title="Le Zapping" class="h4noRedMea txt" >
    <a href="http://www.canalplus.fr/c-infos-documentaires/pid1830-c-zapping.html?vid=1060511" onclick="loadVideoHistory('0','0','0','1830','5794', '1060511', '/c-infos-documentaires/pid1830-c-zapping.html?vid=1060511');return false;">
          26/04/14
                                        </a>
                                                         </h4>
```

Actually my code extract the url like this:

```
self.sous_feuille_canal = http://www.canalplus.fr/c-infos-documentaires/pid1830-c-zapping.html
links = {}
soup = BeautifulSoup(self.sous_feuille_canal)
list_link_canal = []
for link in soup.select('a[href^=http://www.canalplus.fr/]'):
   title = link.get_text().strip()
   if title and 'LIVE' not in title: 
      url = link['href']
      date =    ?                                    # I would like to get the date (26/04/14)
      list_link_canal.append(url)
      links.setdefault(url, []).append(title)        # and add date to my var
      self.list_link_canal = list_link_canal
```

So, I can get the url. But how to get a string like xx/xx/xx between a tags ?
Thanks

Comment: Please give a clear example of the HTML that contains the date you would like to retrieve and it will be easier to help

Comment: link.text? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251319/extract-text-between-link-tags-in-python-using-beautifulsoup

Comment: In this case, `link.string.strip()` would do; but if there are nested tags, `link.get_text().strip()` would be more complete.